# Holes in leaves of Yoshino Cherry

Tags: tree-care, leaves, cherries

I have just started gardening. My first tree purchase was a Yoshino Cherry (Prunus y yedoensis Ivensii). After potting it into a larger pot, it has started to have lots of holes appear in the leaves. I have found 1 leaf with a collection of bugs on it but no idea what they are or how to treat it.

I am in East Lothian, Scotland if that helps.

*click for a larger version*

[image: Holes in Leaf 1]
[image: Holes in Leaf 2]
[image: Bugs 1]
[image: Bugs 2]

**Update**
Image from tips of branches, believed to be new growth but could be a symptom.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Nice pictures. I (tried to) change(d) your post to have them larger, when being clicked, with one of the two images I wasn't able to load a small version (middle)

Comment: Thanks @PatrickB. I had not realised it was possible to create thumbnails on these sites. Added an m to the end of the url shows the medium size. Managed to fix the 3rd image.

Comment: Do you also have wrinkled leaves, as can be seen here: http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4732/leaves-at-the-tip-on-new-branches-of-my-cherry-trees-are-wrinkled

Comment: Only the very last leaf on a branch is curled up, assumed this was new growth. Will update Q with image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's cherry blackfly infestation - needs spraying before the leaf curl gets any worse. Westland Plant Rescue Fruit and Veg bugkiller should do it - you should also use Vitax Winter Tree wash during winter - this pest overwinters on the plant. As the leaves have started curling, its a little late for the Westland spray to be truly effective, but I'd use it anyway, and make sure you treat the tree during winter with the Vitax solution.

If you google cherry blackfly, the RHS advice page on this should come up which will give you alternative proprietary treatments.

Comment: [RHS Cherry Blackfly](http://apps.rhs.org.uk/advicesearch/profile.aspx?pid=488)