# What are these red bumps on my cherry tree stems?

Tags: diseases, cherries, pests

Tiny red bumps started appearing on my multi-variety cherry tree. They only appear on new terminal stems. They do not move.

At first, I thought it was scale pest, so I sprayed neem oil on them twice. That had no effect on them.

Just today, I tried to peel one off with my fingernail. It appears to be fused with the stem, unlike scale. The red peel was thin. Underneath, it was the same green color as the inner stem.

What are these red bumps? Are they pests or part of the tree? This is my first cherry tree, so I know nothing about their peculiarities.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are a natural part of many cherries and are called glands. There is a good picture [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prunus_avium#Description_and_ecology).

No action is necessary on your part. See [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4731/what-are-those-red-dots-on-the-leaf-stems-of-my-cherry-trees) for the same question.

Comment: I don't understand the answer with all its big words. Why do cherry trees in particular need to attract insects with these bumps?

Comment: Why not ask that as a new question?